# making ubuntu run from usb

Tags: boot

hello I am trying to download ubuntu on my 4gb usb and run it on my old laptop with no hard drive, and it isn't working. i need to make it work without using any apps because im downloading ubuntu on usb from chrome.

thanks for your help

Comment: What did you try? I mean, dragging the iso to the USB won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you made your USB bootable? If not use any tool to make USB bootable after downloading the ubuntu OS ISO.

- *To make bootable USB*

-- When on windows, I suggest using Ultraiso: https://www.ezbsystems.com/ultraiso/download.htm

-- If ubuntu: Startup Disk Creator works like a charm.